Is there no autocompletion for interop objects in VS Code?
Using this code:
import win32com.client as win32
xl_ens = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

When I type xl_ens., I do not get auto-completion for the Excel properties and methods, just built in Python stuff
I somehow expected it to pick up on the Excel stuff, especially since it is all extracted to %AppData%\local\temp\gen_py\3.10\. Also, when hovering over the variable in debug-mode, I can see them.
According to this link, early binding should make autocomplete available. What am I missing?
I am using Windows 10 with Python 3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] and Visual Studio Code 1.92.2 with latest versions of Python extensions including Pylance and Python Debugger, Excel 2019 is 32-bit.

You could refer to this answer. This is related to the notion of early and late binding. Pylance is a static language server. It cannot achieve what you want at present.

Tx, but that is the article where I got the code from, and it states there that autocomplete is available when you early-bind like above. Hence my question.

why not use a type annotation?

@starball because I am not that familiar with Python. Will research.

(assuming the package provides full typing stubs for the expected type of the returned object)

Still confused because in debug mode I can see all of it on the xl_ens object. The info is there.

debug mode sees the actual object because it has integration with the python runtime. see static versus runtime analysis

@starball Aha, that is why it can see the Excel api even when dynamic.Dispatch()

Hello, you might try adding a type annotation to your code, like Optional.

@Jeanneli ... Optional what? how is that going to help with what this question is asking for?

You can use the comtypes package to generate the type stubs.
Use type annotations to help the editor understand the type of the variable. For example:
import win32com.client as win32
from typing import Any

xl_ens: Any = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

Then ensure the COM type libraries are generated.
import win32com.client as win32
from typing import Any

win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl_ens: Any = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

By using Any as the type annotation, you help the editor recognize the variable as a COM object, enabling better auto-completion.

"By using Any as the type annotation, you help the editor recognize the variable as a COM object, enabling better auto-completion." Incorrect. Any simply forces the editor to accept all types of objects and thus gives you a full auto-completion list. This has nothing to do with COM objects and isn't "better", either; it just provides more options. If anything it's dangerous because the editor will show auto-completion options that may not result in working code.

@TylerH even that statement of yours is not true.

@starball Then the documentation is also incorrect.
